# C# find first match of string in string array

Tags: c#

I have to search for the first match of any string in an string array in a textbox starting from a certain position. Like if I have this string array:

```
string[] s = { "RTS", "RTL" };
```

And this code:

```
LDA #$43
STA $1000,x
CMP $00
BEQ .main
.return
RTS
.main
add $01
RTL
```

It should return RTS since that's the first match (not the RTL). How can I do this? Additionally, would there be a better way of doing this rather than using an array?

Edited since I gave a bad example of what I was trying to do.

Comment: Could you expand on what exactly your're trying to accomplish? i feel like it would shed some light on how to do it better.  I don't see the correlation between the string and the `gettypefromnum()` method

Comment: Adding the method was pointless I guess, I just used it as an example. I also used C# code as an example. I have a certain piece of code which needs to return in either "RTS" or "RTL", but it doesn't. So what I am trying to do is find the next match of RTS or RTL in the textbox and add it to the code. I hope it's more clear now..

Comment: To elaborate on @TJB's question, what does `offset` mean in this code?  How are the values `0xC0`, `0xCF` and `0x20` determined?  What purpose does the string array `s` serve in your program and this piece of code?  Why should it return `0`?  Is it because there are less than 192 (0xC0) items in the array?  Or perhaps you are scanning the C# code and it finds `"return 0;"` line first, returning the index in the array, `0`.  It appears there is no relation between the two whatsoever.

Comment: I have edited my post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be algorithms to do this efficiently, but I don't know of any.  Fortunately this can be represented easily in code through basic searching.

```
var str = textbox.Text;
var words = new[] { "RTS", "RTL" };
var result = words.AsParallel()
                  .Select(Word => new { Word, Index = str.IndexOf(Word) })
                  .Where(p => p.Index >= 0)
                  .OrderBy(p => p.Index)
                  .Select(p => p.Word)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
if (result == null)
{
    // no match
}
else
{
    // match
}
```

This should be able to run in parallel fine.  If not, remove `AsParallel()`.

---

An alternative approach is to iterate through the string checking for the words picking the first that occurs.  <s>It should perform better than the first.</s>

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length)
                       .SelectMany(i => words.Where(w => str.Substring(i)
                                                            .StartsWith(w)))
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

---

If you'd want the best in terms of efficiency, you'd have to write up a state machine for this but would be very complicated for a simple search of 2 (or more) words.

Comment: I don't think efficiency will be a problem for me as the string I have won't be more than (max) around 2000 lines. Anyway I will test this out and mark your answer right if I can get it to work.

Comment: This code is returning the first string even if the textbox contains both elements. If I have RTL and RTS in the same document and RTL is first, the result is RTS.

Comment: Ah you're right, I've overlooked something and had the semantics reversed.  It's a simple fix however.

Answer (score 0):

The brute force way to do this would be to search the text for every item in the array in turn, storing the index in the text for each one and then return the one with the smallest index.  If the text isn't large and the array is not big (as is with your example) then this would not be a problem.

If you need something fancier, then I would look into generating a [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) on the fly from the array that would go through the text and give you your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want do something like this:

```
    if (offset < 0xC0) 
        execute s[0];   //equals to put "return 0;" here
     if (offset > 0xCF) 
        return 2; 
    if (offset == 0x20) 
        return 4; 
    return 1;
```

That's impossible. We can compile a string of c# code in our program and execute it, see an example [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/skarthikeyan/dynamiccreatingapplication06022005064351am/dynamiccreatingapplication.aspx). But the dynamic code won't effect the current code which generates it.

Comment: As I said before, the C# was just an example code. It's not exactly what I'm trying to do. All I want to do is find the first match of any string in a string array from a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a regular expression along with a simple `list<string>`

Comment: The problem is, I don't know how to create a regex for this. How could I do it?